# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "UMCore"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

### Bug Report

#### Summary of Issue

When running pod install after following the steps to install unimodules by changing AppDelegate.h, AppDelegate.m and Podfile getting an error.

#### Environment - output of `expo diagnostics` & the platform(s) you're targeting

```
Expo CLI 4.0.13 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 11.1
      Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 14.15.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.22.10 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.14.8 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    Managers:
      CocoaPods: 1.10.0 - /usr/local/bin/pod
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 14.3, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 26, 28, 29, 30
        Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 30.0.3
        System Images: android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223
      Xcode: 12.3/12C33 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
      react-dom: ^16.13.0 => 16.13.0 
      react-native: 0.63.4 => 0.63.4 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      expo-cli: 4.0.13
    Expo Workflow: bare
```

#### Reproducible Demo

The error is as follows:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "UMCore":
  In Podfile:
    UMCore (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`)

    UMPermissionsInterface (from `../node_modules/unimodules-permissions-interface/ios`) was resolved to 5.4.0, which depends on
      UMCore

Specs satisfying the `UMCore (from `../node_modules/@unimodules/core/ios`), UMCore` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. npm install --save react-native-unimodules
2. Follow steps here: https://docs.expo.io/bare/installing-unimodules/
3. pod install in the ios directory

#### Expected Behavior vs Actual Behavior

Expected behavior is that pod install works without any errors, but instead getting the error shown in the Reproducible Demo section.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is coming because development target of library `UMCore` pod file is greater than the development target of your project. To solve this find pod file of the UMCore library and check the value of `s.ios.deployment_target`. If the value development target is greater than your project development target then set the same target value for your project development target.

To change the your project development target open project in xcode. From xcode general tab > Deployment Info. Here you can change.